# Approximate Electric Potential $V$ so that it is of the form $V(r) + V(\phi) + V(z)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, approximations

I'm trying to simulate the conductivity of a nanowire that is modeled by a cylindrical shell of infinite potential with benzene rings in the core of the wire. (This is based on a coiled-coil protein structure with Phenylalanine)

In order to compute the Hamiltonian, I require that the electric potential $V$ of the system is of the form $V(r) + V(\phi) + V(z)$ (cylindrical coordinates).

Knowing that the potential is $V = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$, where

$$r = \sqrt{r'^2 - 2r'r\cos(\phi'-\phi) + r^2 + z'^2 - 2z'z + z^2},$$

are there any approximations that I can make that will make that equation separable?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that this site has [MathJax enabled](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which means you can use Latex-like syntax to add in equations for readability. I've set it up for your bottom equation so you can see how it works some.

Comment: what is $r'$ differentiated with respect to?

Comment: Super, it isn't differentiated, there are two spatial  coordinates, one is the source point and the other is the target point. Note we can write $r = \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + ...}$